# How to render a graph with py-script in HTML?

Tags: python, html, numpy, matplotlib, pyscript

I'm experimenting with [py-script](https://pyscript.net/) from the web and I found it interesting.

But in one of my tests doing graphs, I found that it doesn't show me the created graph.

I tried a simple `py-repl` where I paste the code

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pyscript.net/alpha/pyscript.css" />
    <script defer src="https://pyscript.net/alpha/pyscript.js"></script>
    <py-env> 
        - matplotlib 
        - networkx 
    </py-env>
  </head>
  <py-repl></py-repl>
</html>
```

And the Python code I'm trying to run is:

```python
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import networkx as nx

G = nx.Graph()
nodes_california = ["Los Ángeles", "San Diego", "San Francisco"]
nodes_florida = ["Miami", "Orlando", "Tampa"]

G.add_nodes_from(nodes_california)
G.add_nodes_from(nodes_florida)

G.add_edge("California", "Los Ángeles")
G.add_edge("California", "San Diego")
G.add_edge("California", "San Francisco")
G.add_edge("Florida", "Miami")
G.add_edge("Florida", "Orlando")
G.add_edge("Florida", "Tampa")

nx.draw(G, with_labels=True)
plt.show()
```

But as I said, nothing happens:

[image: networkx]

But if I do [this example](https://github.com/pyscript/pyscript/blob/main/docs/tutorials/getting-started.md#the-py-env-tag) with `numpy`.

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pyscript.net/alpha/pyscript.css" />
    <script defer src="https://pyscript.net/alpha/pyscript.js"></script>
    <py-env> 
        - matplotlib
        - numpy
    </py-env>
  </head>
  <py-repl></py-repl>
</html>
```

And the Python code is:

```python
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.random.randn(1000)
y = np.random.randn(1000)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.scatter(x, y)
fig
```

I got this, it does indeed render the figure:

[image: numpy]

How could I manage to render the graph? And yes, packages like matplotlib, networkx and numpy are available ([see the list of available packages here](https://pyodide.org/en/stable/usage/packages-in-pyodide.html)).

Answer (score 0):

Near the top of your Python code, add this line:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
```

Comment out this line:

```
plt.show()
```

And replace with this line:

```
fig
```

Complete example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import networkx as nx

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

G = nx.Graph()
nodes_california = ["Los Angeles", "San Diego", "San Francisco"]
nodes_florida = ["Miami", "Orlando", "Tampa"]

G.add_nodes_from(nodes_california)
G.add_nodes_from(nodes_florida)

G.add_edge("California", "Los Angeles")
G.add_edge("California", "San Diego")
G.add_edge("California", "San Francisco")
G.add_edge("Florida", "Miami")
G.add_edge("Florida", "Orlando")
G.add_edge("Florida", "Tampa")

nx.draw(G, with_labels=True)

fig
```

I also recommend adding these lines so that the **undefined** message in the debugger is fixed. This tells PyScript where to send output.

```
<body>
<div id="image"></div>
<py-script output="image"></py-script>
</body>
```